# try to write python code to execute linux command as different users in same machine

Tags: linux, operating-system, acl, python-3.x, git-submodules

I am trying to write python code which will login as different users one by one and try to fetch permission for different directories for logged users one by one.

```
import os
import subprocess
cmd='echo "testuser" | sudo -S su - {o} -c "{1}"'.format(user_name,method_name(args))
(status, output)=subprocess.getstatusoutput(cmd)
```

Comment: I guess have fun doing that? It's unclear what issue you might be having or what isn't working. Furthermore your current approach doesn't seem to make sense as you would probably be better of using a regular bash script? Also most directory permissions should be directly visible for any user. So there isn't really any reason to login as each user?

Comment: I guess `{o}` is a typo for `{0}` (lowercase o vs number zero), if that's your question.